# NSManagedObject saved in core data but with the wrong attributes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a little problem with my NSManagedObject subclass and the core data.

So, I've created a subclass of NSManagedObject :

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
@objc(Alarm)

class Alarm: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        name = "Unnamed"
    }
}
```

And I've created an **AlarmsManager** class to make the link with the Core Data

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var alarmsMgr: AlarmsManager = AlarmsManager()

class AlarmsManager: NSObject {

let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext
let entityDescription: NSEntityDescription

override init() {
    managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Alarm", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)!
}

func createAlarm() -> Alarm {
    var newAlarm: Alarm = Alarm(entity: entityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    return newAlarm
}

func addAlarm(newAlarm: Alarm) -> Void {
    var error: NSError?
    println(newAlarm.name) // Display the good name
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Error : \(error)")
    }
    println("Done...")
}
}
```

Also, this is how I load my Alarms :

```
func loadAlarms() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Alarm")
    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        alarmsArr = results
    }
    else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

So :

1) I create a new Alarm using **createAlarm**

2) I fill the name of my Alarm using something like **newAlarm.name** = "New name"

3) I try to save this object in my Core data using **addAlarm** from the AlarmManager

**The problem is :** It does save the object in the core data but when I try to display my alarms, the names are still "Unnamed"

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can u check in your Simulator (with an sqlite viewer) if the property is correct in your local database? And try to get the number of alarms - is the alarm count correct?

Comment: Hello, good idea to look into the database if the property is correct, I searched how to do this and I found that I had to go to ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications but then I can't find my application

Comment: Go to ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/...

Comment: Are you using iOS 8?

Comment: Thank you for the path, I found the good file and opend it with sqlitebrowser. There is the good number of objects, the name is good when I just add the alarm but when I stop the app, open it and add another alarm, the names change to "Unnamed". (Edit : Yes, I use iOS8)

Comment: So when you add an Alarm, and check out with an sqllite viewer, everything is fine? when you stop the app, and (check again) everything is fine? Starting again and creating a new alarm and then everything is "unnamed"? Do you mean an empty String, or? So i think your Alarm values get overwritten (Overwrite Values?)

Comment: By "Unnamed" I mean a string called "Unnamed" as you can see in my "Alarm" object. So, I reseted the simulator, I launched it and create an alarm and I stopped the simulator. In the sqlite there is my alarm with the good name "Test1". I launched the app, the alarm was loaded but displayed "Unnamed". I created a new alarm, quit the simulator, look at the database and "test1" became "Unnamed" and "test2" was still "test2" but when I started again the simulator, I had two "Unnamed" alarms.

Answer (score 0):

I added the NSManagedObjectContext rollback function in the function that display the AlarmsListView and my problem was solved.